# Can Accessibility Service get text from screen Android?

Tags: service, accessibility

Can Accessibility Service get text from screen Android?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Android AccessibilityService can indeed retrieve text from the screen. The AccessibilityService class in Android provides various methods and callbacks that allow you to access and interact with the user interface elements on the screen.

```
 @Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    int eventType = event.getEventType();

    // Check if the event type is a text change event
    if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) {
        CharSequence text = event.getText();
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            // Process or use the retrieved text here
            Log.d("AccessibilityService", "Retrieved text: " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED)